# Oauth2 for a headless device having a user_code

Tags: oauth-2.0, headless

At the moment I am trying to implement `oaut2` authentication for a headless device. I found [this documentation](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/device-flow/authorization-server-requirements).

And I like to use the part of the docs with the header:
*Optimization for Non-Textual Interfaces*

The question I have is that I like to set the `user_code`, but I don't know where. So I like to use this URL:

https://authorization-server.com/device?user_code=BDWD-HQPK

Can anyone point me to an example or tutorial?

Comment: Or you use client_id or you use Authentication. So problem solved as I can use the authentication header